# Tag [dynamic] is very ambiguous and seldom describes the content

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request, clean-up

The tag [dynamic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic) is very ambiguous and does not well describe the content in the question and I struggle to think of a question where it can work as the *only* tag for the question. I consider this to be a good example of a [meta tag](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/) that provide little value - both for users that answer and that asks.

From [The Death of Meta Tags](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/):

> How can you tell you’re using a meta-tag? It’s easier than you might think.
>
> - If the tag can’t work as the only tag on a question, it’s probably a meta-tag. Every tag you use should be able to work, more or less, as the only tag on a question.
> - Meta-tags are actually a subset of a larger problem that I usually call dependent tags. These are tags that don’t say anything by themselves – you can’t tell what the question is about unless they’re paired with some other tag

There are situations where people want to use something *dynamic* in the tags, but there are more specifics for that, e.g.

- [dynamic-typing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-typing) (266 questions) - some programming languages have dynamic types
- [dynamic-variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-variables) (221 questions) - similar to above
- [dynamic-keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-keyword) (23 questions) - e.g. C# has a keyword `dynamic`
- [dynamic-programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-programming) (4523 questions) - an algorithmic technique
- [dynamics-crm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamics-crm) (7045 questions) - a specific [CRM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Customer-relationship_management) system
- [dynamic-memory-allocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-memory-allocation) (2535 questions) - related to data structures and memory allocation
- [dynamic-linking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-linking) (1396 questions) - in contrast to static linking
- [dhtml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dhtml) (735 questions) - old term for  "Dynamic HTML", a webpage using JavaScript

### How ambiguous is [dynamic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic)?

Let us see some of the ten [latest questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic):

- How to handle landing page with dynamic content for multiple clients? - related to [angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular)
- Make new page from input? - related to [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) and navigation
- Suppose I have malloced a memory of 10 bytes. Can we free 11 bytes? - related to [malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/malloc)
- Dynamically update variables for Google Cloud Functions? - related to [google-cloud-functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-functions)
- Can I change the app icon and name after app installation in Flutter for an Android app? - related to [flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flutter)
- Is it possible to change the increment of a range which controls a for loop within the for loop? - related to [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python)

### Should any action be taken?

My opinion is that tag [dynamic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic) is used for so many different ambiguous things that it is not useful. If this tag would not exist, I think users would use a more specific tag or omit this aspect of the question - perhaps use a more descriptive tag instead. Any thoughts on actions? Can it be burninated? Cleaned up?

Comment: I don't see value for this tag. It doesn't seem to add any clarity or useful information to a question. Removing it from a question that has it very likely leaves the same meaning intact. Unless that happens to be *the only* tag on a question, in which case the question is very likely lacking information already.

Comment: Everything on a computer is `dynamic`! IMHO a useless `tag`.

Comment: @PoulBak Except that **dynamic RAM** uses **static electricity**, whereas **static RAM** disappears without a **current** source.

Comment: That `dynamic-keyword` tag is _really_ bad.

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera: I consider it better than [tag:c#] [tag:dynamic].

Comment: @Joshua no, it's way worse. It's the equivalent to having tags named `if-keyword`, `var-keyword` and so on.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Burn it to the ground. You missed some cases though

- [dynamic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic) [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) -> [dynamic-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-sql) [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) for dynamically generated SQL questions (there's quite a few). Normally we'd squash both tags when doing something like this, but we keep [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) because it's a language tag.
- [dynamic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic) -> [dynamic-compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-compilation) may happen but it's not the most likely of mistake.
- Some questions would almost certainly be better served by [cache-coherency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cache-coherency) or [cache-invalidation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cache-invalidation). It will be apparent on discovering one.

Comment: I didn't meant to list all case, just to provide _some_ examples of how different topics are posted within this same tag. There are many more, just see the example questions I posted as well :)

Comment: @Jonas: It is said the more comprehensive the burnination guidance the better.

Comment: 25k questions, that's gonna be a hell of a job!

Comment: @DidierL: We can cut that down enormously if we're willing to unleash bots to handle the obvious cases.

Comment: You have a small typo. I think you mean dynamic and dynamic-sql instead of dyamic and dyamic-sql.